# SQL: how to get membership based on ALL from a given cohort

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables in a MySQL database:

**team**

```
team_id   name
3         Rangers
12        Capitals
19        Red Wings
4         Bruins
212       Avalanche
102       Flyers
20        Islanders
50        Sabres
7         Stars
```

**player**

```
id    name
2     Zach
1     Deb
17    William
9     Viktor
12    Andrew
41    Chris
22    Bobby
5     Phil
3     Roy
92    Li
6     Juan
```

**players_in**

```
team_id   player_id   points
3         2           42
212       2           19
3         12          18
19        12          2
3         41          2
4         41          1
212       41          78
212       17          1
19        41          4
12        41          2
3         17          6
4         1           9
102       1           40
102       22          7
20        22          19
20        5           22
50        3           20
12        92          15
12        17          8
7         6           12
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle with the data:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/989ebe/1

I would like to get the `name` and `id` of the players who have played on **ALL** of the teams that Zach has played on.

In this case, Zach has played for the Rangers and the Avalanche.

Therefore, the desired result set would be:

```
name       id
William    17
Chris      41
```

(because these players were part of **both** the Rangers and the Avalanche teams)

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct p.* 
from player p
  join players_in pi on pi.player_id = p.id
  join player p2 on p2.name = 'Zach'
  join players_in pi2 on pi2.team_id = pi.team_id
                and pi2.player_id = p2.id
where
  p.name <> 'Zach'
  and not exists (select 1 from players_in pi3                   
                  where pi3.player_id = p2.id
                      and pi3.team_id not in (select team_id 
                                              from players_in pi4 
                                              where pi4.player_id = p.id));
```

First of all I've joined players_in (pi) with players (p) obtaining the set of all players and theirs teams.

Second, cross joined player zack joined with player_in (pi2) obtaining the set of Zach's teams. Joined pi2 with pi I've obtained the set of all player that had played in a Zach's team.

Now the where conditions:

- p.name <> 'Zach' will exclude Zach from my list.
- The not exists condition is the hard part of the query.
  I've selected all Zach teams again (pi3) not in the set of the player's (p) team,

[SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/989ebe/62)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement could be translated to: searching for players which there's not exists any Jack's team that they don't play in. Corresponding query could be:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT p1.name, p1.id
FROM
  player p1 
  INNER JOIN players_in pin1 ON p1.id = pin1.player_id
WHERE
  name != 'Zach'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM 
      team t 
      INNER JOIN players_in pin2 ON t.team_id = pin2.team_id
      INNER JOIN player p2 ON p2.id = pin2.player_id
    WHERE 
      p2.name = 'Zach' 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM players_in pin3 
                      WHERE pin2.team_id = pin3.team_id 
                        AND pin1.player_id = pin3.player_id)
  );
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/989ebe/61

Answer (score 0):

Using a `cte` for Zach's games and then checking all potential memberships based on `team_id` existence in the `cte`'s values:

```
with cte as (
   select pi1.team_id from players_in pi1 join player p2 on p2.id = pi1.player_id 
   where p2.name = 'Zach'
)
select p.* from player p where (select count(*) from cte c) = (select 
    sum(pi1.team_id in (select c.team_id from cte c)) 
    from players_in pi1 where pi1.player_id = p.id) and p.name != 'Zach'
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YQI0dFEO).

Comment: This query works until there are not duplicated in players_in table